# configure apache to use mod_rewrite and mod_dbd using postgreSQL and PHP

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up Apache to use mod_rewrite and mod_dbd with postgreSQL for a club website. (Kubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.2)
 I can find some details for mod_dbd with mySQL, but I am having a very hard time with this combination. Any hints, suggestions or answers appreciated.

My current VirtualHost config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap  myquery    "dbd:SELECT page_name FROM page WHERE page_identifier = (%s)"
    RewriteMap  revquery   "dbd:SELECT page_identifier FROM page WHERE page_name = (%s)"

    RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?id=${revquery:$1} [L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}          id=(\d+)
    RewriteRule ^/index\.php?         /${myquery:%1}?    [R=307,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I have moved the following into the main config file and added a few more default statements. (And removed the <IfModule> tags)

```
DBDriver  pgsql
DBDParams "hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5436 dbname=page user=user password=pass"
DBDMin      1
DBDKeep     2
DBDMax     10
DBDExptime 60
```

Notes

- Actual domain name redacted. It's not in any shape for public
  inspection
- what I have is partially based on answers to these two questions
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623195/assistance-with-a-rewriterule-using-rewritemap
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite
  as well as
  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dbd.html
- I am using a non-standard port for PostgreSQL and the pages work if I
  use the unmodified URLs. They are being created from the same
  database that I want mod_dbd to access.
- the expected urls will be index.php?id=X, where X is a positive integer

Edit 4:
 - removed a lot of details regarding missteps
 - I was originally missing `RewriteEngine On`
 - I also had the RewriteMap statement wrong. The parameter apparently needs to be %s, although I am not sure exactly what that means
 - I found out that the <IfModule> tags were not necessary and I removed them. I probably want an error if those modules are missing!

Edit 5: it's now working!! Details changed above.

Meta question: Should I revert the question to an earlier form and move some of this info to an answer, or just leave it like this?